# Facing issue while scrolling a list in ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I am making a portal where in one module I'm having a list of items. On touch of each item a pop-up will appear and will display the corresponding order's details.
The problem I'm facing is, which scrolling down the popup is appearing, that should not happen. 
Can anybody suggest me how to prevent this?
the popup should only appear on touch of item not on scrolling.
below is the code how I'm managing it for android.

```
$(document).on('click', '.mobile-click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(new String(e.target.className) != "icon-info-order") {
    if(parseInt(isViewMode) === 1) {
      showFlagOrder(jQuery(this).find('.flag-order'),true,e.pageY-100)
    } else {
      showEditOrder(jQuery(this).find('.edit-order'),true,e.pageY-100)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: a scroll starts with a touch so I assume that could be a problem. I came here because you had a tag iOS and iPhone. You should add a jQuery or JS tag too.

Comment: Yeah that is the issue, how do iphone developer manage tap and scroll?